# The term 'Get-SPWeb' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: sharepoint-online

I tried to run a script from [Bulk delete files from library using name of file](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/208732/bulk-delete-files-from-library-using-name-of-file)

```
$webUrl = ''
$listName = ''
$query = '<Where>' +
    '<Contains>' +
    '<FieldRef Name="FileLeafRef"/><Value Type="Text">bad_file</Value>' +
    '</Contains>' +
    '</Where>'
$viewFields = '<FieldRef Name="FileRef"/><FieldRef Name="FileLeafRef"/>'
$delete = $false

Start-SPAssignment -Global

try {
    $web = Get-SPWeb $webUrl
    $list = $web.Lists[$listName]
    $spQuery = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
    $spQuery.Query = $query
    $spQuery.ViewFields = $viewFields
    $spQuery.ViewFieldsOnly = $true
    $spQuery.ViewAttributes = 'Scope="Recursive"'
    $items = $list.GetItems($spQuery)
    $items | Select-Object ID, @{Name="FileName";Expression={$_["FileLeafRef"]}} |
        Export-Csv -Path ".\FilesToDelete.csv" -NoTypeInformation
    if ($delete) {
        $batch = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
        $batch += '<ows:Batch>'
        foreach ($item in $items) {
            $batch += '<Method>'
            $batch += '<SetList Scope="Request">' + $list.ID + '</SetList>'
            $batch += '<SetVar Name="Cmd">Delete</SetVar>'
            $batch += '<SetVar Name="ID">' + $item.ID + '</SetVar>'
            $batch += '<SetVar Name="owsfileref">' + $item["FileRef"] + '</SetVar>'
            $batch += '</Method>'
        }
        $batch += '</ows:Batch>'
        $web.ProcessBatchData($batch)
    }
}
catch {
    Write-Error $_
}

Stop-SPAssignment -Global
```

And I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\admin\Documents\scripts\scripts.ps1 : The term 'Get-SPWeb' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
path is correct and try again.
```

Is the function deprecated? If so, what replaces it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error usually comes if you directly run the command in the Windows PowerShell Console.

To resolve to execute the below command first:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell
```

Ideally, we should run in SharePoint 2013 Management Shell rather than only in the PowerShell console. So Open SharePoint 2013 Management Shell in Administrator mode and then run the Cmdlet the error will not come.

If you are using the Windows PowerShell ISE to run, debug or test PowerShell cmdlets, then you can write the script like below:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell
$web = Get-SPWeb “http://win-pfcp2dgt8di/sites/EnjoySharePoint/”
```

Reference URL :

https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/the-term-get-spweb-is-not-recognized/

**Troubleshooting:**

We may get the below error:

**add-pssnapin : No snap-ins have been registered for Windows PowerShell version 5**

**Need to follow the below:**

Please make sure that you run the PowerShell on a SharePoint Server machine.

The PowerShell script below can get a list of snap-ins that are registered on your computer:

```
get-pssnapin –registered
```

More information about Add-PSSnapin:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849705.aspx

For the details troubleshooting - please refer the below articles:

[add-pssnapin : No snap-ins have been registered for Windows PowerShell version 5](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/582435)

[Powershell Add-PSSnapin produces "No snap-ins have been registered for Windows Powershell version 4"](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/664ca8b5-551e-4956-8912-c718e1661a79/powershell-addpssnapin-produces-quotno-snapins-have-been-registered-for-windows-powershell?forum=sharepointadmin)

Comment: Add-PSSnapin : No snap-ins have been registered for Windows PowerShell version 5.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell:String) [Add-PSSnapin], PSArgumentExce
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AddPSSnapInRead,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddPSSnapinCommand

Comment: Updated the answer - need to follow some troubleshooting for the above error

Comment: Ah, do you absolutely run it on a powershell on a sharepoint server machine? How do you batch delete if you don't have a powershell running on a sharepoint server machine?

Answer (score 3):

You tag your thread as SharePoint online so I suppose you're using SharePoint online.
Get-SPWeb is SharePoint module for on-premise only.

You could use [PnP PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps) or CSOM PowerShell instead.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you did not load the SharePoint module.   Add this as the first line of your script.

Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell